# Create a Mailing List from Master Data with Checkbox Function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I am trying to use the checkbox function of Google Sheets to filter data from one sheet to another. Basically, I would like to create a mailing list in a separate sheet. When the checkbox "Wants mail" is ticked on the master data sheet for a contact, I would like to only have these contacts pop up in the mailing list sheet.[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=filter('Master Data'!A2:H; 'Master Data'!I2:I)`

Put the formula in cell `A2` in the mailing list sheet.

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).